XSLT - separate single attribute into mutliple elements with attributes
I have some source XML that contains cross-references to multiple values within one attribute. I need to separate these into their own distinct elements with attribute values.
Input XML:
<p>Blah blah blah <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref004 ref005 ref006 ref007">4&#x2013;7</xref>.</p>

Desired Output XML:
<p>Blah blah blah <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref004">4</xref><xref
        ref-type="bibr" rid="ref005"/><xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref006"/>&#x2013;<xref
        ref-type="bibr" rid="ref007">7</xref>.</p>

Notice the 2 cross-references in the middle become empty elements.
I have the following XSLT but it's not getting me the correct output - it's inserting the attribute values as element content.
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="xref">
    <xsl:variable name="rid" select="@rid"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($rid, ' ')">
            <!-- Multiple references -->
            <xsl:variable name="refs" select="tokenize($rid, ' ')"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="$refs">
                <xsl:if test="position() > 1">
                    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:variable name="refNum" select="substring-after(., 'ref')"/>
                <xsl:element name="xref">
                    <xsl:attribute name="ref-type">bibr</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="rid">
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat('ref', $refNum)"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <!-- Single reference -->
            <xsl:element name="xref">
                <xsl:attribute name="ref-type">bibr</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="rid">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$rid"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>


"the 2 cross-references in the middle become empty" Why? And why does the first xref contain all the original rids?Please the explain the required  logic in words.

They are empty as they have no text content (implied references). First xref was overlooked - just edited to provide correct desired output.

I am afraid that's not a sufficient explanation. What is the exact rule for dividing the content of the original xref?

I think I am getting the expected result by using :
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="xref[contains(@rid, ' ')]">
    <xsl:variable name="ref" select="text()"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(@rid, ' ')">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="position()=1">
                <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="{.}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($ref, '&#x2013;')"/>
                </xref>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="position()=last()">
                <xsl:text>&#x2013;</xsl:text>
                <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="{.}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($ref, '&#x2013;')"/>
                </xref>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="{.}"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

But that is mostly based on guessing what the rules are, based on your single example...
